# ID SQLite doesn't autoincrement

Tags: android, sqlite, unique

I have this code:

```
package com.example.jessi.moopooh;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jessi on 17/06/2016.
 */
public class BDJuego extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String NOMBRE_BD = "bdmoopooh.db";
    private static final int VERSION_BD  = 1;
    private static final String TABLA_PUNTUACIONES = "CREATE TABLE puntuaciones" +
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, nombre_juego TEXT NOT NULL, nombre_nivel TEXT NOT NULL, puntos INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE(_id, nombre_nivel))";

    public BDJuego(Context context) {
        super(context, NOMBRE_BD, null, VERSION_BD);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TABLA_PUNTUACIONES);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLA_PUNTUACIONES);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void insertarPuntuaciones(String nombre_juego, String nombre_nivel, int puntos) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        if(db != null){
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues(); //como su nombre indica es un almacenador de un conjunto de datos
            //valores.put("_id", id);
            valores.put("nombre_juego", nombre_juego);
            valores.put("nombre_nivel", nombre_nivel);
            valores.put("puntos", puntos);
            db.insert("puntuaciones", null, valores);
            db.close();
        }
    }

    //Este método no sé si lo usaré
    public void modificarPuntuaciones(int id,String nombre_juego, String nombre_nivel, int puntos){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
       // valores.put("_id", id);
        valores.put("nombre_juego", nombre_juego);
        valores.put("nombre_nivel", nombre_nivel);
        valores.put("puntos", puntos);
        db.update("puntuaciones", valores, "_id=" + id, null);
        db.close();
    }
    //Este método no sé si lo usaré
    public void borrarPuntuaciones(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("puntuaciones", "_id="+id, null);
        db.close();
    }
    //Recuperar solo una puntuacion. No sé si lo usaré
    public Puntuaciones recuperarPuntuacion(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String[] valores_recuperar = {"_id", "nombre_juego", "nombre_nivel", "puntos"};
        Cursor c = db.query("contactos", valores_recuperar, "_id=" + id,
                null, null, null, null, null); // El método query nos devolverá un Cursor que podremos recorrer para recuperar todos los registros de la base de datos
        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Puntuaciones puntuaciones = new Puntuaciones(c.getString(1),
                c.getString(2), c.getInt(3));
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return puntuaciones;
    }

    //Recuperar todas las puntuaciones
    public List<Puntuaciones> recuperarTodasLasPuntuaciones() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        List<Puntuaciones> lista_puntuaciones = new ArrayList<Puntuaciones>();
        String[] valores_recuperar = {"_id", "nombre_juego", "nombre_nivel", "puntos"};
        Cursor c = db.query("puntuaciones", valores_recuperar,
                null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Puntuaciones puntuaciones = new Puntuaciones(c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(2), c.getInt(3));
            lista_puntuaciones.add(puntuaciones);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        db.close();
        c.close();
        return lista_puntuaciones;
    }
}
```

But I don't know why id doesn't autoincrement and colum id and colum nombre_nivel are unique but the db allow me insert data with the same name... what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNIQUE(_id, nombre_nivel)` means the combination of those independent fields are unique, not the fields themselves.

> For each UNIQUE constraint on the table, each row must contain a
>   unique combination of values in the columns identified by the UNIQUE
>   constraint.

[Source](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints)

Try with

```
CREATE TABLE puntuaciones(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, nombre_juego TEXT NOT NULL, nombre_nivel TEXT NOT NULL, puntos INTEGER NOT NULL, UNIQUE(nombre_nivel))
```

Comment: But the id always is 0. https://gyazo.com/18cd89ac69b41db86a63abac0a93712e

Comment: I tested it, works fine. Make sure you dropped the previously existing table so it is created again. You can adb pull the database to check it.

Comment: I made a mistake with my class constructor and for this reason it didn't work well. But now it works fine :) Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Update your field `TABLA_PUNTUACIONES` to contain the following `SQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE puntuaciones (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre_juego TEXT NOT NULL,
  nombre_nivel TEXT NOT NULL,
  puntos INTEGER NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (nombre_nivel) ON CONFLICT FAIL
);
```

The column `_id` will be autoincremented.

The column `nombre_nivel` will be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the help but id always is 0 and I don't know why happen this :/ The logcat say me this: https://gyazo.com/18cd89ac69b41db86a63abac0a93712e